# How to dynamically generate and show only those columns in primeng table which exist and have data in an array

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have an array which has records as object,the object sequence is not same.The object will skip from backend if they have empty.Like below.

```
let cities = [
    {name: 'Los Angeles', population: 3792621,country:"USA"},
    {country:"USA"},
    {name: 'Chicago'},
    {population: 2099451},
    {name: 'Philadelphia', population: 1526006}
];
```

I need to generate columns for the primeNg p-table and show only those records which has data.I am doing it  in this way.

Step#1.Getting data from service like this

```
let cities = [
        {name: 'Los Angeles', population: 3792621,country:"USA"},
        {country:"USA"},
        {name: 'Chicago'},
        {population: 2099451},
        {name: 'Philadelphia', population: 1526006}
    ];
this.mapData(cities);
```

Step#2.Mapping it to class Model

```
mapData(cities){
     let returnArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    city = new CityModel();
    city.name=cities[i].name || "";
    city.population=cities[i].country || "";
    city.country=cities[i].population || undefined;
      returnArray.push(city);
    }
    return returnArray
}
```

Step#3.filtering return mapData for generating columns

```
showOnlythoseColumnWhichHasData(cities){
      let cols:[]=[];
      for (var i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
        if(cities[i].name==""){
            cols.push(
            {field: 'name',
            header: 'Name',
            key: 1,
            display: false
            }
        }
        else {
        cols.push(
            {field: 'name',
            header: 'Name',
            key: 1,
            display: true
            }
        }
            if(cities[i].country==""){
            cols.push(
            {field: 'country',
            header: 'country',
            key: 1,
            display: false
            }
        }
        else {
        cols.push(
            {field: 'country',
            header: 'country',
            key: 1,
            display: true
            }
        }
            if(cities[i].population==""){
            cols.push(
            {field: 'population',
            header: 'population',
            key: 1,
            display: false
            }
        }
        else {
        cols.push(
            {field: 'population',
            header: 'population',
            key: 1,
            display: true
            }
        }
      }
}
```

In step#3 I am confused how to check every records and fill up the cols array accordingly.

I try my best to explain.If something missing please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to push a object to the cols array for each property in the cities object, and tell it to display only if that property has a value.

This is what I would do. If I missed something let me know.

```
showOnlythoseColumnWhichHasData(cities) {
    let cols = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
        //looping through the properties of the city object
        Object.keys(cities[i]).forEach((property: string) => {
            cols.push({
                field: property,
                header: property,
                key: 1,
                display: (cities[property] != "") //resolves to true/false
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I need the columns are gettting duplicate which I need to avoid,I need show one columns one time

Comment: I need to made display true or false based on Object.values(columns[i]) to make it true if the values exist in case value is undefined or empty I needs to mark it false in next step.